# adding fadein effect with inner.HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, innerhtml

Looking to fade-in content when using inner.HTML.

Current code;

```
<td style="width: 20%;" class="responsive-td" valign="top">
          <div id="placeholder1" class="placeholder1" style="color:white;"></div>
        </td>

if (//logic here){

          document.getElementById('placeholder1').innerHTML ='add this with fading effect';

          setTimeout(addFn1, 300);
           function addFn1() {
            document.getElementById('placeholder2').innerHTML ='add this with fading effect';}       

    setTimeout(addFn2, 1200);
           function addFn2() {
            document.getElementById('placeholder3').innerHTML ='add this with fading effect';}
         }
```

I attempted using css however it doesn't create the effect due to setTimeout.

Is there a simple solution using CSS or JS? Or even jQuery if need be?

Comment: May be you can try using `opacity` set to old=zero to new=one while changing text

Answer (score 1):

That is easy to do with jQuery, since there are methods for simple animations like this.

Have a look at [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

```js
if (true){

  $('#placeholder1').html('add this with fading effect').fadeIn(600);

  setTimeout(addFn1, 300);
  function addFn1() {
    $('#placeholder2').html('add this with fading effect').fadeIn(600);}       

  setTimeout(addFn2, 1200);
  function addFn2() {
    $('#placeholder3').html('add this with fading effect').fadeIn(600);}
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.placeholder1{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td style="width: 20%;" class="responsive-td" valign="top">
  <div id="placeholder1" class="placeholder1" style="color:white;"></div>
  <div id="placeholder2" class="placeholder1" style="color:white;"></div>
  <div id="placeholder3" class="placeholder1" style="color:white;"></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using opacity set to old=zero to new=one while changing text.

**Option**: Using CSS3 and Js(no jquery)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var quotes = ["Hello", "there", "everyone"];
  var infos = document.querySelectorAll('div.info');
  var repeat = Array.prototype.slice;
  var fadeIn = function(i) {
    if (!infos[i]) {
      return;
    }
    infos[i].innerHTML = quotes[i];
    infos[i].classList.add("open");
  };
  repeat.call(infos).forEach(function(el) {
    var callBack = function(e) {
      var that = this;
      repeat.call(infos).forEach(function(cur, ind) {
        if (cur == that) {
          fadeIn(1 + ind);
          return false;
        }
      });
    };
    el.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', callBack);
    el.addEventListener('animationEnd', callBack);
  });
  fadeIn(0); /* trigger fade */
});
```

```css
.info {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(0%);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1px 2px;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(0%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(100%);
  }
}

.info.open {
  -webkit-animation: fade .3s;
  -moz-animation: fade .3s;
  -ms-animation: fade .3s;
  -o-animation: fade .3s;
  animation: fade .3s;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```